# Limit code completion in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.4, xcode7-beta4

Is there any way I can have code completion as follows in Xcode (6.4 or 7)

Assume I have a line

```
DDLogDebug(@"Retrieved file content %@",fileTitle);
```

I now wish to change it to DDLogVerbose

I put my cursor on the D(after g) and type a V

[image]

I then hit enter and have to manually delete the "(" "the content" and the ")". This is three extra keystrokes in this scenario.

```
DDLogDebug(<#frmt, ...#>)(@"Retrieved file content %@",mediaItem.fileTitle);
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do it in fewer keystrokes.

Comment: You can always use common selection shortcuts like cmd+shift+right. They are similar at all moderns OS's and are saving tons of time.

Comment: CMD + shift + right , not quite what I was hoping for